# xpath not recognized in selenium, but is recognized in XPather

Tags: java, xpath, selenium

I have the following code in my script:

```
System.out.println(selenium.getAttribute("xpath=//div[@class='guest clearfix'][1]/@id"));
```

When I try to run the script, it says the element is not found.  If I enter the xpath into XPather (addon for firefox) `//div[@class='guest clearfix'][1]/@id`, it will correctly give me the id.

I am stumped as to why it will not run in my code.  If anyone can see any error in my code, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: <div id="id-74385" class="guest clearfix" style="z-index: 999;">

I am trying to get the id from this snippit, where the number is a dynamically generated number and not known at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem will be the extra forward slash before the @id. Try the following:

```
selenium.getAttribute("//div[@class='guest clearfix'][1]@id");
```

I believe the final `/@id` is valid XPath for returning an attribute, but Selenium's syntax is different as it requires an element locator followed by an `@` and attribute name.

Additionally, you could achieve the same with the following CSS locator:

```
selenium.getAttribute("css=div.guest.clearfix@id");
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I tried both suggestions that you posted, and both are still not finding the element.  The error I am recieving is:

com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element //div[@class='guest clearfix'][1] not found

and when I try CSS, I get:

com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element css=div.guest.clearfix[1] not found

Comment: It'd be worth updating your question with a snippet of the HTML. Is it possible that the element has loaded when the command runs? If so, it might be worth adding a `waitForCondition` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the problem isn't with the attribute, but with the basic locator itself. I suggest you play with the [$x function](http://blog.browsermob.com/2009/04/test-your-selenium-xpath-easily-with-firebug/) in Firebug and make sure that locating the *element* first (not the attribute) works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what SeleniumIDE shows in its Reference section:

Arguments:

- attributeLocator - an element locator followed by an @ sign and then the name of the attribute, e.g. "foo@bar"

So, Dave's answer is correct.